# android progressbar in notification open activity when click

Tags: android, notifications

I just wonder that is it possible to make progressbar in notification and open an activity when click it.

Let's make a sample:
I have Activity A, B and C which C is file upload Activity with progressbar and notification.

So, when i click HOME button and then click notification icon i want to back to Activity C, Clicking back button go to Activity B and clicking again go to Activity A.

Here is my Fileupload and notification class

Activity C

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_c);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.x = -20;

    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        params.height = 750;
        params.width = 550;
    }
    else
    {
        params.height = 550;
        params.width = 750;
    }

    params.y = -10;

    this.getWindow().setAttributes(params);

    pg = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    pg.setProgress(0);
    new RunProgress().execute();
}

public class RunProgress extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        if(extraFlag == 0)
        {
            // Call Notification method
            // backup is executed
            displayNotification();
        }

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fileName.size(); i++)
        {
            name = fileName.get(i);

            WebDav writer = new WebDav(getApplicationContext(),
                    name);
            try
            {
                x += percentage;
                publishProgress("" + x);
                writer.uploadFile(name);

                if (isCancel)
                    break;
                File file = new File(new FilePathClass().returnSimple()
                            + name);
                file.delete();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                system.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress)
    {
        pg.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        //  This makes Notification icon CLEAR
        myNotificationManager.cancelAll();
    }
}

and notification method
private void displayNotification()
{
    n = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    n.setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.msg_action_bar_title));
    n.setTicker("Uploading...");
    n.setContentText("Upload progress started");
    n.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

// This makes return to Same Activity 
// when clicking notification icon
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityC.class);
//      i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    i.putExtra("extraFlag", 1);
    i.putStringArrayListExtra("fileName", fileName);
    i.putExtra("numberOfContacts", fileName.size());

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(ActivityC.this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ActivityC.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(i);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    n.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ActivityC.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (currentApiVersion < 16)
        myNotificationManager.notify(0, n.getNotification());
    else
        myNotificationManager.notify(0, n.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `setLatestEventInfo()` on the Notification object, supplying a `PendingIntent` that will start your activity when they tap on your entry in the notification drawer. 
[Check out this sample.](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Notifications/Notify1/)

Comment: Dear Ronny. Thanks for message. It works. However, i want to bring Activity C as background and progressbar as popup. It was my fault to mention that Activity C calls Activity D as dialog. So, clicking notification icon must show Activity C as background and Activity C calls Activity D as popup which is exact same state where i left off.